# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{\mathit{e}^{n}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{\mathit{e}^{n}}$.

Here is what I tried:

$a_{n}=\frac{1}{\mathit{e}^{n}}$. Then $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\mathit{e}^{n+1}}$. Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{\mathit{e}}$, right? Then $\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{\mathit{e}}}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$, since $\lim_{x\to \infty}\mathit{e}^{\frac{1}{x}}=1$.

Then the radius of convergence is 1, right? However, I don't think what I did was correct. Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't take the $n$th root after doing the ratio test. The ratio test, if it works, already gives you the radius of convergence: in your case, $1/e=1/r$.

The root test can be used to find the radius of convergence when the ratio test doesn't work i.e. $a_{n+1}/a_n$ doesn't converge (for example, if infinitely many $a_n$ are zero). In this case $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$ gives you $1/r$. The root test can also be used when the ratio test does work.

Comment: My bad! Thanks! I was mixing up the ratio and root test together, hahaha....

Comment: Even when the ratio test works, the root test can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

Set $ X=\frac{z}{\mathrm{e}} $, know that the series $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 0}{X^{n}} $ converges if and only if $ \left|X\right|<1 $, thus the series $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 0}{\frac{z^{n}}{\mathrm{e}^{n}}} $ converges if and only if $ \left|z\right|<\mathrm{e} $, which means the radius of convergence would be $ \mathrm{e} \cdot $

Comment: Let $ n $ be an integer greater than $ 1 $ and let $ z $ be a point from the unit cercle. $ z=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,\theta} $ for some $ \theta\in\left]0,2\pi\right[ $, then $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{z^{k}}=\frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\, n\theta}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,\theta}} $, which does not have a limit when $ n $ approaches $ +\infty \cdot $

Comment: As I said, even in the complexe plane, the series converges if and only if $ \left|w\right|<1 \cdot $

Comment: Yes, you are correct!  My earlier comments were mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{R}=\lim\sup |a^n|^{1/n} = \lim \sup \left[\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^n\right]^{1/n}=\frac{1}{e}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It's a geometric series; it's value is $\frac{1}{1-z/e}$, provided that $|z|<e$.